# how to disable the row of the grid view

Tags: asp.net

how to disable the row of the grid view when grid view is in page indexing such that suppose in 1st page if 2nd row is disabled then in second page 2nd row should not be disabled

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it on the RowDataBound event.